# Script in AutoHotkey to Press Windows button and Left Arrow simultaneously

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write a script in autohotkey so that every time I open my dictionary application on PC, keys <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> being pressed at the same time and as the result, it snaps the windows on the left side of monitor.

I tried this:

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
Send, #{Left}
return
```

Also this one:

```
#IfWinActive Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary
Send, {LWinDown}{Left}{LWinup}
return
```

But for either of them noting happened when I opened the application.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @Charlie Armstrong the real question is: **How do I make a block of code run every time I start a certain program?** So `#IfWinActive` might not be useful for.

Comment: You need to trigger this code somehow.  `#If` directives apply to hotkeys, but you're missing any hotkey declaration.  Is this in the auto-execute section?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I don't know what is auto-execute section. how can I recognize it is here ?

Comment: More or less, is it at the top of your script @Soheil

Comment: The auto-execute section is the beginning of the script, as defined [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).  It runs automatically when you start the script.

Comment: @Spyre No it is not. at first lines I have script for doing things when other windows active ( I used  another #if for other application too before it )

Comment: It seems that the issue is that you don't ever execute the code you've written.  *When* do you want it to send `Win`+`Left`?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I've been put the file of script in windows startup. I would like the windows be on left side of monitor every time I opened it ( or every time the windows is active) but I should also note that when it is on the left side it is not necessary to send Win+Left hotkey anymore. (but I think it is enough for me if every time I open it, it sends the keys because normally I wouldn't move the windows after it placed on the left side)

Comment: Okay, so now you've got a much more complicated problem.  To start at the root of the problem, do you see why your code doesn't work?  You've got a [`#IfWinActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive in there, but you don't have any hotkey to apply it to.  AutoHotkey still doesn't know *when* you want to run that code.  So your real question is "How do I make a block of code run every time I start a certain program."  Does that make sense?  If so, can you edit all this into the question so someone can write a relevant answer?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Thank you for the suggestion. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is periodically check if new process/window is created and to check if that is a process/window we want to interact with.

This first example is based on COM notifications when a process has been created/destroyed.

```
; help for question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66394326/883015
; by joedf (16:04 2021/02/28)

MyWatchedWindowTitle := "Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary"
NewProcess_CheckInterval := 1 ; in seconds
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;this might not be needed, makes the check for "contains" instead of "same" winTitle
hWnds := []
gosub, initialize_NewProcessNotification
return

; Called when a new process is detected
On_NewProcess(proc) {
    global hWnds
    global MyWatchedWindowTitle
    
    ; get the window handle, if possible
    if (hwnd:=WinExist("ahk_pid " proc.ProcessID)) {
        WinGetTitle, wTitle, ahk_id %hwnd%
        
        ; check if there is a visible window
        if (wTitle)
        {
            ; if so, check if it's a window we want to interact with
            if (InStr(wTitle,MyWatchedWindowTitle))
            {
                ; check if we've interacted with this specific window before
                if (!ArrayContains(hWnds, hwnd)) {
                    ; we havent, so we do something with it
                    hWnds.push(hwnd) ; keep in memory that we have interacted with this window ID before.
                    DoSomething(hwnd) ; the keys we want to send to it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

DoSomething(hwnd) {
    ; size and move window to the left
    SysGet, MonitorWorkArea, MonitorWorkArea
    posY := 0
    posX  := 0
    width := A_ScreenWidth // 2
    height := MonitorWorkAreaBottom
    WinMove, ahk_id %hwnd% ,,%posX%,%posY%,%width%,%height%
    
    ; multi-montitor support, more examples, and more complete snapping functions can be found here:
    ; https://gist.github.com/AWMooreCO/1ef708055a11862ca9dc
}

ArrayContains(haystack, needle) {
    for k, v in haystack
    {
        if (v == needle)
            return true
    }
    return false
}



initialize_NewProcessNotification:
;////////////////////////////// New Process notificaton ////////////////////////
; from Lexikos' example
; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/56984-new-process-notifier/#entry358038

; Get WMI service object.
winmgmts := ComObjGet("winmgmts:")

; Create sink objects for receiving event noficiations.
ComObjConnect(createSink := ComObjCreate("WbemScripting.SWbemSink"), "ProcessCreate_")
ComObjConnect(deleteSink := ComObjCreate("WbemScripting.SWbemSink"), "ProcessDelete_")

; Set event polling interval, in seconds.
interval := NewProcess_CheckInterval

; Register for process creation notifications:
winmgmts.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(createSink
    , "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent"
    . " within " interval
    . " where TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Process'")

; Register for process deletion notifications:
winmgmts.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(deleteSink
    , "Select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent"
    . " within " interval
    . " where TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Process'")

; Don't exit automatically.
#Persistent
return

; Called when a new process is detected:
ProcessCreate_OnObjectReady(obj) {
    proc := obj.TargetInstance
    /*
    TrayTip New Process Detected, % "
    (LTrim
        ID:`t" proc.ProcessID "
        Parent:`t" proc.ParentProcessID "
        Name:`t" proc.Name "
        Path:`t" proc.ExecutablePath "
        
        Command line (requires XP or later):
        
        " proc.CommandLine
    )
    */
    On_NewProcess(proc)
}

; Called when a process terminates:
ProcessDelete_OnObjectReady(prm) {
    /*
    obj := COM_DispGetParam(prm, 0, 9)
    proc := COM_Invoke(obj, "TargetInstance")
    COM_Release(obj)
    TrayTip Process Terminated, % "
    (LTrim
        ID:`t" COM_Invoke(proc, "Handle") "
        Name:`t" COM_Invoke(proc, "Name")
    )
    COM_Release(proc)
    */
}
```

This second example, which is perhaps a bit simpler, checks periodically for new windows that match the searched `WinTitle`.

```
; help for question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66394326/883015
; by joedf (16:17 2021/02/28)

#Persistent

MyWatchedWindowTitle := "Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary"
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;this might not be needed, makes the check for "contains" instead of "same" winTitle
SetTimer, checkForNewWindow, 1000 ;ms
hWnds := []
return

checkForNewWindow() {
    global hWnds
    global MyWatchedWindowTitle
    
    ; first check if there is at least one window that matches our winTitle
    if (hwnd:=WinExist(MyWatchedWindowTitle)) {
        ; get all window matches
        WinGet, wArray, List , %MyWatchedWindowTitle%
        
        ; loop through all windows that matched
        loop % wArray
        {
            hWnd := wArray%A_Index%

            ; check if we've interacted with this specific window before
            if (!ArrayContains(hWnds, hwnd)) {
                ; we havent, so we do something with it
                hWnds.push(hwnd) ; keep in memory that we have interacted with this window ID before.
                DoSomething(hwnd) ; the keys we want to send to it
            }
        }
    }
}

DoSomething(hwnd) {
    ; size and move window to the left
    SysGet, MonitorWorkArea, MonitorWorkArea
    posY := 0
    posX  := 0
    width := A_ScreenWidth // 2
    height := MonitorWorkAreaBottom
    WinMove, ahk_id %hwnd% ,,%posX%,%posY%,%width%,%height%
    
    ; multi-montitor support, more examples, and more complete snapping functions can be found here:
    ; https://gist.github.com/AWMooreCO/1ef708055a11862ca9dc
}

ArrayContains(haystack, needle) {
    for k, v in haystack
    {
        if (v == needle)
            return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Woow ! It worked perfectly!! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest issue is that AHK doesn't seem to work well for snapping windows (according to my quick research and testing). What does work well, though, is [WinMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm).

I assume you're launching the program from a shortcut icon, but I would suggest using a keyboard shortcut that launches the program and then positions the window from the script. Here is some sample code that opens Notepad2.exe, waits for 200 milliseconds, and then moves the window and resizes it:

```
^+!n:: ; Control+Shift+Alt+N to Open Notepad
Run C:\Program Files\Notepad2\Notepad2.exe
sleep, 200
WinMove, Notepad2,, 10, 20, 800, 600
return
```